# Increasing screen brightness Toshiba Tecra M2

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, display

I recently reinstalled windows on my Toshiba Tecra.

I needed to lower brightness for a little bit and the laptop was not responding to my fn+f6 so I restarted the laptop and as soon as it turned on I was pressing the fn+f6 the screen brightness did go down. The problem is that now I cannot get it to be brighter again.

I have tried downloading the Added value pack but it has failed with an error; and all the solutions I see posted are for Windows 7 when I run windows XP SP3 on this computer.

The model number is M2-S530

I would like to fix my fn keys, but fixing the brightness will be enough for me to be satisfied. I've already tried to install all the drivers from the toshiba website.

I have failed (the drivers all crash on installation go figure)  but even if I have succeeded It would not have fixed my problem. 
Other solutions do not work for me because they are mostly for windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the "Added value pack" is, but it sounds like you didn't install all the drivers and utilities for that notebook from Toshiba when you reinstalled Windows.  If true, then that's probably why those extedned keys aren't funcitoning.

Here's a [link to the driver set](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=596873&rpn=PTM20U&modelFilter=M2-S530&selCategory=2756709&selFamily=1073768664) (toshiba.com) for the Tecra M2-s530, and driver for both XP and XP SP2/3 are there.

[image]

Comment: Actually i tried to install the drivers starting with the bios one yet this one failed and from then on all the other drivers fail as well. They are most likely not going to fix the fn functionality from what i've read.